# proc sql to create a column with count values

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset,named, mydata with variables: date, unique ID, x1,x2,x3 and x4.

```
proc sql;
create table cat&yyyymmdd
as select unique ID, sum(x1+x2)/count(*) as PART1, sum(x3+x4)/count(*) as   from mydata&yyyymmdd group by unique ID;
run;
```

I would like to have two count columns(count1 and count2) in my final table with part1, part2. Basically the count(*) values corresponding to PART1 and PART2 values for each unique ID by dates.

Hope this makes sense. Please Help! thanks..

Comment: I cannot understand this part::"Basically the count(*) values corresponding to PART1 and PART2 values for each unique ID by dates."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count(*)` values will be identical - they will be the count of non-unique values of ID in both cases.  The following query illustrates (I guess):

```
proc sql;
create table cat&yyyymmdd as
   select UNIQUE_ID /* assume is correct spelling of "unique ID" */
      , sum(x1+x2)/count(*) as PART1
      , sum(x3+x4)/count(*) as PART2
      , count(*) as count1
      , count(*) as count2 /* !! */
  from mydata&yyyymmdd 
  group by 1; /* more robust syntax */
run; /* should be a quit; but a quit; is not necessary either */
```

note that "select UNIQUE ID" is not valid syntax, although the UNIQUE keyword is permissible when creating an index:

```
CREATE <UNIQUE> INDEX index-name
  ON table-name ( column <, ... column>);
```

Comment: No problem.  A word of advice - Stackoverflow aims to be a useful resource or 'knowledgebank' if you will.  Your questions (especially clear ones like above) are contributing to this knowledgebank.  However messages of thanks / appreciation actually introduce clutter - so it's much better to show your appreciation by just voting and / or accepting answers.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, It surely helped. Actually I'm very new to stackoverflow. I don't have sufficient points to vote. Just give me a day, I'll surely vote for your answers as they helped me alot..